# jquery getScript problem with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I've this script

```
$.getScript('page.asp?t=' +timestap);

page.asp generate this:

MyFunction({
  "result" : {
    "error" : false/true,
    "delete" : false/true,
    "data" : 'escaped html data'
  }
});
```

with Firefox it works like a charm, 
but with Internet Explorer result.data is empty

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Is the content-type of page.asp set to server "text/javascript"?